# How can I define the LAMBDA function in LISP?

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

I can't use at all lambda function, because I get this error:
Argument to apply/funcall is not a function: (LAMBDA (E) (COUNT_ATOMS M E)).

And the code is:

```
> (DEFUN count_atoms (m l)
>     (COND ((ATOM l) (COND ((EQUAL m l) 1)
>                       (t 0)))
>       (t (APPLY '+
>                 (MAPCAR '(LAMBDA (e) (count_atoms m e))
>                         l)))))
```

For

> (count_atoms 3 '( (3 3) 3 (4 4) 5))

it should print 3.

What is wrong here?

Comment: @WillNess: You should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `(MAPCAR #'(LAMBDA (e) (count_atoms m e)) ...`, with the "sharp" sign. Same with  `apply`, use `#'+`.

writing `#'(lambda .... )` is the same as writing `(function (lambda .... ))`. There's also a macro `lambda` which lets you get away with writing just `(lambda ... )` there.

see also:

- [CLHS: apply](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_apply.htm)
- [CLHS: function designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_designator)